# Storing information in the DOM?

Tags: jquery, optimization, dom

Im making a small private message application in the form of a phone. Ten messages are shown at the time. And the list of messages are scrolled up/down by hiding them.

Just how bad is it to use the DOM to store information in this way. My main goal for doing this is to reduce calls to the database. And instead of making a new call all the time, it only checks if any new messages has arrived and ads the new message(s).

Whats the alternative, cookies anyone?

Thank you for the time

EDIT: To clarify
The messages (id, title, date, from, content) is stored in a ul list, when scrolled the first and the last is hidden/shown. 
10 elemnts is shown at the time.

Comment: If you are storing it in the DO its not persistent, so why don#t you just store it in a JavaScript object?

Comment: So an object can hold relative large strings just fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "using the DOM to store information", do you just mean hiding elements and showing them later? In that case, I think it's just fine. There's no need to fetch things one at a time if you can fetch ten and just reveal them one at a time.

Comment: Er, to be clear -- there is a balance where it is better to fetch fewer than more, but you get the idea.

Comment: I fetch about 20 messages, at the time. The content is moved to new elements when a message is opened though

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what you mean by moved to new elements when a message is opened -- you may want to see if you can achieve most of what you want using CSS and classes (i.e., a class for a hidden message, a class for a show message, and a class for an opened message). It's not always possible, but I've always found it the cleanest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

jquery has a [store](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function.

Comment: Is performance worth the inconvenience. Looks like I need to do quite a bit of extra code. Or perhaps I need to read up on better examples

Answer (score 0):

How many are you actually displaying at a time?  Do you mean you fetch 20 and only display 1?  or 5?

I would make a DIV with overflow: scroll, and let the user scroll up and down.  Or use overflow: hidden and add some JavaScript to move it up and down however you like.  Then you only need to manipulate the DOM when somebody goes past what you've pulled up and you need to pull more.

If you want to do it with the DOM, just change the CSS of a particular message to display: none to hide things as needed.  Unless these messages are huge or something I see no problem with pulling a bunch of them from the DB and hiding/showing them as needed.

Comment: I display, 10. Hmm overflow you say, heard of it, so many new gems out there :)
Been using the hide show method. 
The application will be used on a browser based game. The game/site will use a lot of jQuery.